# How to check for equality with an array element in Vuejs v-if?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

i am working in a vuejs project and i am with a problem to check if a number is equal to an Array element. My code is this:

```
<div v-if="someValue != arrayElement">
   //
</div>
```

My problem is how i loop through the array to check if there is an equal value to the var 'someValue'.

Comment: *equal to an Array element* `v-if="arrayElement.includes(someValue)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.includes(value)` if you want to test an exact value

```
new Vue({
    data: function() {
        return {
            value: 3,
            array: [3,4,5,6,7,3]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isInArray: function() {
            return this.array.includes(value);
        }
    }
})
```

Or directly in `v-if` directive like that

```
<span v-if="array.includes(value)"> {{ value }} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is create computed property that filter your array by specific value. For example:

```
new Vue({
  data: function() {
    someValue: 3,
    array: [3,4,5,6,7,3]
  },
  computed: {
    arrayFiltered() {
      return this.array.filter(elem => elem === this.someValue);
    }
})
```

and in your html this may be look like this:

```
<div v-if="array.includes(someValue)">
   <div v-for="elem in arrayFiltered" :key="array.indexOf(elem)">
     {{ elem }}
   </div>
 </div>
```

So that way you can specify your array to be array of objects, for example